# PlaceAutocompleteFragment show "Can't load searching result"

Tags: android, placeautocompletefragment

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

        autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
                new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596)));

        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .build();

        autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);


        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
                // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Place:" + place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error" + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

The searching is not working. When I type place name in the searching text box. It show "Can't load the searching result". I cann't solve it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Remove this setBoundsBias and try

Comment: removed, but it still have that problem

Comment: In Google console place API enable or not ?

Comment: I have already enable the Google Places API for Android

Comment: Something went wrong with your google account or google play service implementation. Because i test your code is working fine,

Comment: Can I know the step of creating the google play service implementation?

Comment: Thanks you for helping me to test the code

Comment: i have add   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps

Add dependencies in project gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Add dependencies in main Gradle

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

At Last you need to add **google-services.json** file in you project